# Serviceworker conflict with HTTP basic auth?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, basic-authentication, service-worker

I'm trying to protect a site during an early stage of development from casual prying eyes. Basic auth over HTTPS seemed like a reasonable solution but the presence of a serviceworker seems to prevent it from working in Chrome.  This happens specifically if a serviceworker is already installed, but the browser does not have an active authorisation for the desired realm.

Chrome shows that the response was a 401 in the network timeline

[image: 401 in Network timeline]

And also shows that the browser tab is receiving the right response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My realm"
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 03:09:35 GMT
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But it does not prompt for a login, it just shows the content body of the 401 response.

Is this a Chrome bug, or is it likely to be a problem with my ServiceWorker?

Comment: How does Chrome know to send auth headers with the service worker request?

Comment: @RickViscomi the serviceworker doesn't, but the tab should, right?  The SW ought to be an uncaring middlebox in this process, that's what I assumed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I demoed this to one of the Google engineers responsible for implementing ServiceWorker in Chrome, and he determined that it was a Chromium bug.  Filed here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623464#

Comment: From the bug tracker: **I don't think the expected behaviour of showing an authentication dialog box is ever going to happen** because the service worker may run at any time and having a dialog box popping up at an odd time will look like "magic". Discussion:
https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/119

Answer (score 8):

This is because of a `fetch()` option unfortunately defaults to `'omit'` credentials. You need to `fetch()` with `{'credentials': 'same-origin'}`. Watch for the [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/585).

For now if you are using `add()` or `addAll()` you will need to pass a request object.

**Example:**

```
cache.addAll(
  cacheUrls.map(url => new Request(url, {credentials: 'same-origin'}))
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using `fetch(request)` in my service worker and adding  a line with `request.credentials = "same-origin"` fixed this issue.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 83 anymore. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623464#